# Help Identifying This Custom Sprayed Specialized...?

Tags: identify-this-bike, specialized-bikes

[image]Can anyone from the pictures identify this specilized frame? Im assuming its a Specialized FSR of some description as its been re-stickered at some point? Serial number has been sprayed over so cant really tell. Any help is appreciated.

Regards
Luke[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like an earlier Specialized FSR stuntjumper.

Answer (score 3):

A Specialized FSR XC between 2005 and 2008. See the [Blue Book](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/product/10575) for variants on the pierced and forged seat tube style.

Note: That’s a really low end shock on the bike. Unless Specialized did a budget coil shock for really low end versions for some markets I’m guessing that’s a replacement. The original air shock on my 2006 FSR XC Comp wore through and I had find a replacement.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the information just did want to mislead anyone.